# Growing an element on the spot in CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a lot of spans that are boxes in a `center` tag and I want each box to grow on the spot when the user hovers over it. This doesn't work, because it shifts all the other elements along with it and doesn't look nice:

```
.square:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 50px; // originally 25px
    height: 50px;// originally 25px
}
```

How can I get it to grow without shoving all of its neighbors aside?

Comment: How do you layout the squares? With `float`?

Comment: @j08691 They're arranged in a triangle, so it seemed to be the quickest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wrap the .square in an relatively position container of the same size, then on hove make .square absolutely positioned

```
.squareContainer { 
    position:relative; 
    width: 25px; 
    height: 25px;
}
.square:hover { 
    position:absolute; 
    width: 50px; 
    height: 50px;
}
```

This way when .square is removed from the flow it doesn't affect other elements.
EDIT

Setting .square to absolute doesn't seem to work
but setting both to relative works

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UD9yM/)

http://jsfiddle.net/ur4aT/10/

Comment: But when I do this, the square doesn't grow anymore. Here's a link to the fiddle, by the way: http://jsfiddle.net/ur4aT/8/#run

Answer (score 1):

Give `.square` position absolute and position it relative to it's container...

```
.square { 
    position:absolute; /* moves the element out of normal flow */
}

.square:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 50px; // originally 25px
    height: 50px;// originally 25px
}
```

You may also need to alter the `top` and `left` properties in the `:hover` psuedo-selector since positioning is based off of the top left corner of the element:

```
.square { top:50px; left:50px; }

.square:hover {
    /* ... definitions ... */

    top:25px;
    left:25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used the trick

1. set the outer `div`s position to  `inline-block` to  align them horizontally (not required thou')
2. set the width and height of outer `div` (required)
3. use `%` based dimensions for inner `div` (choose whatever you like, and it's simple to work that way).
4. on inner div `:hover` state, set it's dimensions again `%` based and set it's `margin` a/c to formula `margin = (100-width)/2`

Check out the demo @jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dxb28/,

best of luck :)<