# Image Change/Enlarge on Hover without Effecting Page Spacing

Tags: javascript, css, hover, onmouseover, onmouseout

I am currently using onmouseover and onmouseout to swap images on hover. This is working great, but now we would like to add the effect of [this scroller](http://www.jscraft.net/demo/plugins/scroller/demo2.html) - basically, adding the functionality that if image A is 20x20 and the image shown upon hover is 80x80 - how can I get the hover image to open "on top" of the others so the increase in image size does not affect the container or table?

There are a few requirements: The solution needs to work in **IE7** and must have the ability to display a different, larger image on hover.

Comment: You can use a css3 transform (scale or a matrix) with a transition. Its support is not universal (ie9+ for transforms, ie10 for transitions.)

Comment: similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11255586/growing-an-element-on-the-spot-in-css/

Comment: Thanks. I understand the concept of swapping an image as well as transform. However, I am needing to combine the two and have not seen a solution that does this.

Answer (score 0):

You can scale it with CSS3.

Here's an example of transform: scale - [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Jmeks/2/)

And here's the code I used in my example:

```
<div class="box"></div>

.box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: green;
    -webkit-transition: 0.1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: 0.1s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: 0.1s ease-out;
}

.box:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.4);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.4);
    -o-transform: scale(1.4);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.4);
}
```